# unix command to extract part of a hostname

Tags: unix

I would like to extract the first part of this hostname `testsrv1` 
 from `testsrv1.main.corp.loc.domain.com` in UNIX, within a shell script.

What command can I use? It would be anything before the first period `.`

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can use [`cut`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cut_%28Unix%29):

```
echo "testsrv1.main.corp.loc.domain.com" | cut -d"." -f1
```

Comment: This isn't really doing it within a shell script as much as asking `cut` to do it.

Answer (score 33):

Do you have the server name in a shell variable?  Are you using a `sh`-like shell?  If so,

```
${SERVERNAME%%.*}
```

will do what you want.

Answer (score 26):

To build upon pilcrow's answer, no need for new variable, just use inbuilt $HOSTANME.

```
echo $HOSTNAME-->my.server.domain
echo ${HOSTNAME%%.*}-->my
```

Tested on two fairly different Linux's.

**2.6.18-371.4.1.el5, GNU bash, version 3.2.25(1)-release (i386-redhat-linux-gnu)**
 **3.4.76-65.111.amzn1.x86_64, GNU bash, version 4.1.2(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)**

Comment: This is assuming the question is about the hostname of the server the shell is running on. If it was, then this would be correct - and is probably helpful for some users who come across this question/answer. But, as asked, this answer is actually wrong.

Comment: Under macOS it is `HOST`.

Comment: @zaTricky Agreed. Sometimes as IT people we have to interpret what people ask vs what they actually need. I'm glad a few people found my answer helpful. The nice thing about unix is there are always several ways of doing something - none wrong - but some are prettier than others.

Answer (score 25):

try the -s switch:
hostname -s

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: perfect! To me it seems significantly cleaner than just cutting away based on `.`'s.

Answer (score 5):

I use command `cut`, `awk`, `sed` or *bash variables*

### Operation

Via **cut**

```
[flying@lempstacker ~]$ echo "testsrv1.main.corp.loc.domain.com" | cut -d. -f1
testsrv1
[flying@lempstacker ~]$
```

Via **awk**

```
[flying@lempstacker ~]$ echo "testsrv1.main.corp.loc.domain.com" | awk -v FS='.' '{print $1}'
testsrv1
[flying@lempstacker ~]$
```

Via **sed**

```
[flying@lempstacker ~]$ echo "testsrv1.main.corp.loc.domain.com" | sed -r 's@([^.]*).(.*)@\1@g'
testsrv1
[flying@lempstacker ~]$
```

Via **Bash Variables**

```
[flying@lempstacker ~]$ hostName='testsrv1.main.corp.loc.domain.com'
[flying@lempstacker ~]$ echo ${hostName%%.*}
testsrv1
[flying@lempstacker ~]$
```

Answer (score 1):

You could have used "uname -n" to just get the hostname only.

Comment: This makes the assumption that the host string being parsed is always for the host the code is executing on. Since the OP has not specified that, the OP probably wants to be able to do that for any FQDN string, so your answer would not apply.

Answer (score 1):

You can use IFS to split text by whichever token you want. For domain names, we can use the dot/period character.

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env sh

shorthost() {
  # Set IFS to dot, so that we can split $@ on dots instead of spaces.
  local IFS='.'

  # Break up arguments passed to shorthost so that each domain zone is
  # a new index in an array.
  zones=($@)

  # Echo out our first zone
  echo ${zones[0]}
}
```

If this is in your script then, for instance, you'll get `test` when you run `shorthost test.example.com`. You can adjust this to fit your use case, but knowing how to break the zones into the array is the big thing here, I think.

I wanted to provide this solution, because I feel like spawning another process is overkill when you can do it easily and completely within your shell with `IFS`. One thing to watch out for is that some users will recommend doing things like `hostname -s`, but that doesn't work in the BSD userland. For instance, MacOS users don't have the `-s` flag, I don't think.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the variable `$HOSTNAME` exists, so try `echo ${HOSTNAME%%.*}` to get the top-most part of the full-qualified hostname. Hope it helps.

If interested, the hint is from the below quoted **partial `/etc/bashrc` on a REHL7 host:**

> ````bash
>       if [ -e /etc/sysconfig/bash-prompt-screen ]; then
>           PROMPT_COMMAND=/etc/sysconfig/bash-prompt-screen
>       else
>           PROMPT_COMMAND='printf "\033k%s@%s:%s\033\\" "${USER}" "${HOSTNAME%%.*}" "${PWD/#$HOME/~}"'
>       fi
>       ;; ... ```
> ````